# call jquery changePage() on localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a simple jquery mobile page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.2">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="MyContainer">

        <!-- ##################### Raw Part ##################### -->
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1> Hello World </h1>
            </div>                        
        </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

when I execute that page it renders fine with a black header and title.

The reason why that page loads correctly is because jquery-mobile placed new attributes where needed in fact the innerHTML of MyContainer after the page loads is:

```
<!-- ##################### Parsed Part ##################### -->
<div data-role="page" data-url="/jqueryMobile/TC_Page/main2.html" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 1464px;">
    <div data-role="header" class="ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner">
          <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">
                Hello World
          </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

In other words the *Raw Part* turn into the *Parsed Part* .

**I will like to know what jquery.mobile function made the conversion from the Raw Part to the Parsed Part!**

**The functions `$.mobile.changePage()`, `$.mobile.loadPage()` enables me to do that** For example I could do:

```
// place response from SomeUrl inside the div MyContainer and convert it from raw to parsed!
$.mobile.loadPage('SomeUrl', { pageContainer: $('#MyContainer') });

// later then get the child child (note second child) of MyContainer and make that the child of MyContainer
```

### The problem now is:

All those functions: loadPage, ChangePage etc make an ajax call. **What if I already have the html that I want to inject ( I have it in webBrowser local storage or in a Cookie)!**  In other words how can I make this work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.2">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="MyContainer">



    </div>

    <script>
        function SomeFunction(){

             var someHTML = localStorate.html1;   // html1 = raw part = <div data-role="page"><div data-role="header"><h1> Hello World </h1></div></div>

             $("#MyContainer").html(someHTML);

             // now here I am stuck!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
             // how can I make the content of MyContainer go from the raw part to the Parsed Part!
             // I am looking for something like:


             $JqueryMobile.ParseHTML($("#MyContainer"));
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

**`jQuery Mobile`** provides numerous functions for widget restyling but only one of them will restyle whole page.

```
    $('#index').trigger('pagecreate');
```

Where **`#index`** should be an id of your page **`DIV`**.

There is also on other function that can be used here, but unlike **`trigger('pagecreat');`** this function will style only DIV wit **data-role="content"** attribute. To test this, jsFiddle example **`trigger('pagecreate');`**  should be replaced with **`trigger('create');`**

```
    $('#index').trigger('create');
```

If possible **SCRIPT** tag should not be used inside a **BODY** tag, while it will work it can cause additional problems. If you want to find more about this topic and how **`jQuery Mobile`** handles dynamically added content take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)** which is a part of my **`personal blog`**.

### Example

Working example: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AzXdT/)

This part of code should interest you:

```
$('#index').append('<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h1>Dynamicaly added footer</h1></div> ');
$('#index [data-role="content"]').append('<fieldset data-role="controlgroup"><legend>Choose:</legend><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" value="1" checked="checked" /><label for="radio1">option 1</label></fieldset>');
$('#index').trigger('pagecreate');
```

This code is used to dynamically append page footer and a radio button to page content.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. That seems to work on regular jquery stuff but it does not work on jquery-mobile tags. Maybe I am doing something wrong I will try more

Comment: Gajotres the jsFiddler you just posted is exactly what I need for some reason I cannot make it work. I posted a question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537486/cannot-make-jsfiddle-example-work hoping someone could explain my why the same code does not work on my website. I will appreciate if you could tel me what could be the problem